# Logout slow on 22.10

Tags: shutdown, logout, 22.10

Did a fresh install of 22.04, then upgraded to 22.10. I noticed that logging out from Gnome takes a very long time (about 10 seconds!) on 22.10, while it was pretty much instant on 22.04. Is anyone else experiencing this? Any ideas on where to look to find the issue?